How do I find the first term of an arithmetic sequence given two partial sums?
The sum of the first five terms of an arithmetic sequence is 75. The sum of the first eleven terms of this sequence is 363. What is the first term of the sequence?
My thought process:
Since $S_{n} = \frac{n(a_{1}+a_{n})}{2}$,
$S_{5} = 75 = \frac{5(a_{1}+a_{5})}{2}$
And $S_{11} = 363 = \frac{11(a_{1}+a_{11})}{2}$
I tried to solve the system of equations, but I realized that there were 3 unknowns, with only 2 equations. I also tried to use the property $d = \frac{a_{n}-a_{m}}{n-m}$ in order to perhaps solve $a_{n} = a_{m}+(n-m)d$, but I couldn't figure out how to get two different terms of the sequence.
I feel like that last part about finding the common difference to find $a_{1}$ is the way to go, but I don't know how to find two different terms of the sequence, or maybe there's another way... Can anybody help?

Well, if you write $a_i = a_1 + (i-1)\times d$, then you will have only 2 variables.

The third term of the sequence (the middle term of the first five) is $\frac{75}{5}=15$.  The sixth term of the sequence (the middle term of the first eleven) is $\frac{363}{11}=33$.  Therefore, $d=\frac{33-15}{3}=\frac{18}{3}=6$, so $a_1=15-2 \cdot 6=3$

Yeah he forgot to put the \frac before the {18}{3} but whatever. I understand what he means

@Person12343 all sorted now

Wait - I just realized. What if you have an even number for the partial sum? For example, if you were given the partial sum of the first 6 and 12 terms instead?

Then you'll end up with terms $3.5$ and $6.5$, but when you subtract them you'll still have the difference between $3$ terms.
